# play framework alternate application.conf file slick datasource connection failing

Tags: playframework, configuration, slick

I have my application working with application.conf.  I now want a copy of this application to be running differently, so I created an alternate conf file for this instance.

The application runs and I can access static resources, however, endpoints that need to access the datasource do not respond.  Is this a Slick limitation?  What is wrong here?

application.conf

```
play.crypto.secret = "onlyHoudiniKnows"    
play.i18n.langs = [ "en" ]
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?user=myuser"
slick.dbs.default.db.password="password"
```

alternate.conf

```
include "application"

play.crypto.secret="onlyDavidCopperfieldKnows"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myalternatedb?user=myalternateuser"
http.port=9005
play.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=true
```

startserver.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting My Server..."
/myserver-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/myserver -Dconfig.file=/myserver-1.0-SNAPSHOT/conf/alternate &
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in your include statement in `alternate.conf`

You need to keep the file extension like..

```
include "application.conf"
```